# Calculating the refractive index of water with the Ewald-Oseen formula

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, refraction

The [Ewald-Oseen theorem](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.19330) gives the expression
$$n=\sqrt{1+\frac{i\sigma}{\epsilon_0\omega}}$$
for the refractive index of a material of conductivity $\sigma$ for an electromagnetic wave with angular frequency $\omega$. But this doesn’t seem to work with, for example, water, which has a refractive index of about $1.333$ (with a very small imaginary part) for visible light.

I’m not a materials expert, so I don’t know what sort of conductivities different materials have, so I must resort to Google for that. If I google “conductivity of water”, I get results in the ([$4.2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials)$-$[$5.0$](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=conductivity+of+water)) $\times 10^{-5}$ S/m range for deionised water at room temperature, which doesn’t give the  correct refractive index. Even if I take the value for seawater of $5$ S/m, it doesn’t add up.

For light with a wavelength of $550$ nm, $\omega$ is about $3.4\times10^{15}$ Hz. $\epsilon_0$ is about $8.854\times10^{-12}$ F/m. If I throw all of that into the Ewald-Oseen equation, I get $n \approx 1+10^{-9}i$ for deionised water and $n \approx 1+10^{-4}i$ for seawater.

What gives?

Comment: How did you obtain the values of $n \approx 1$ for the real part? Can you see that the real and complex terms are added with a square root. Ewald-Oseen theorem, linked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewald%E2%80%93Oseen_extinction_theorem) gives a simplification of $n = \sqrt{1 + \chi_e}$ where it cancels out the complex part.

Comment: Also, $\sigma = -i \epsilon_0 \omega \chi_e$. So if you place this into the Ewald-Oseen equation above, it will cancel out the complex term. You just need to find the value of $\chi_e$ for water.

Comment: With the conductivity of saltwater, the real part of $n$ is 1.000000003..., which is why I said it’s practically 1.

Comment: I’m aware it can be written as a function of the susceptibility. But it should work either way, shouldn’t it? I’m just confused it doesn’t work with the conductivity. The $i$ also seems weird: while I understand the derivation of the Ewald-Oseen formula, I don’t see how the conductivity could be a complex (or imaginary) number, which it needs to be for transparent materials (which have refractive indices that are almost real).

Comment: So then the $\sigma$ in the Ewald-Oseen theorem should be the (complex) *admittivity* of water, not just its conductivity, because it comes from the current density being proportional to the electric field. Thanks!

Comment: In such cases when the conductivity must be expressed as a complex number, such as with alternating electric fields, it is called the admittivity. Admittivity is the sum of a real component called the conductivity and an imaginary component called the susceptivity. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Complex_resistivity_and_conductivity).

Comment: The imaginary component of complex conductivity is susceptivity (in analogy to reactance). If you remember from alternating current circuits, impedances $X_R$ and $X_C$, $X_L$ are at 90∘ and 180∘ to each other. That is the reason they have a complex component. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Complex_resistivity_and_conductivity).

Comment: The conductivity is imaginary because the microscopic current density is out of phase with the electric field in a dielectric.